# Regex to find a string within two strings but excluding anything that starts with http?

Tags: html, regex, search, replace, sublimetext

Right now I'm using `(?<=href=")(.*?)(?=#fragment-[0-9]">)` which returns anything in between href=" and #fragment-[any number between 0 and 9]" which is basically what I want, but I want to exclude things like href="http://blahblah.com#fragment-1" or href="https:blahblah.com#fragment-1" so what can I change the `(.*?)` to to exclude strings starting with http or https.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(?<=href=")(?!https?:)(.*?)(?=#fragment-[0-9]">)
```

Also, [don't use regex to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/505154).

Comment: not parsing html, im searching through an html document to fix broken links, thanks